# AS3: Is it possible to give a vector function argument a default value?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function where I'd like to make a vector argument optional-- that is, something like this:

```
public function test(arg1:int, arg2:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(5)) {}
```

So in that example, I want the first argument to be required, and an optional vector passed in. If the second argument is not provided, create an int vector with 5 elements instead. It throws a compile error: "Parameter initializer unknown or is not a compile-time constant."

Making the argument *not* optional works, as in:

```
public function test(arg1:int, arg2:Vector.<int>) {}
```

But that's not exactly what I'm looking for. Doing some searching I found a supposed workaround, which is

```
public function test(arg1:int, arg2:Vector.<int> = null) {}
```

But that doesn't compile either.

I've already moved on in my code with a workaround just to be done with it, but I'm still curious. Can you have a vector as a default argument, and how?

Comment: I guess the compiler should tell you something that it is not a compile time constant. You cannot instantiate an object in your parameters list. It won't work with Array, won't work with Object, won't work with Vector. It will work with primitive values, null, undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.  Probably just because the compiler was never programmed to handle this situation because optional parameters do work with many other datatypes in AS3.  I did some research and other have reported the same issue as you with no success in setting an empty vector object in the function declaration.

I would simply do the following if you haven't already:

```
var myDefaultVector:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(5);

function test(arg1:int, arg2:Vector.<int> = null) {
    if( arg2 == null ) {
        arg2 = myDefaultVector;
    }

    // rest of your code
}
```

I have tried compiling the above code in Flash and it compiled successfully.

Comment: Ah hah; it looks like the last example wasn't compiling because I made a typo. Fixed. Still not exactly what I was looking for but is good to know.

Comment: yea, I noticed you were missing the `.` in your declarations, forgot to mention that in my post. ;)